# how can i assign indented block in vim a special syntax highlighter?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

for convenience in grouping couchdb functions
i created a file format that groups separate things together using yaml

it basically contains entries in the form of `name.ext: |`
followed by a intended block of code in the language fitting to .ext

for more pleasant editing i'd like to have vim use the correct syntax highlighters for them

*edit*

some code examples as requested

simple:

```
map.coffee: |
  (doc) ->
    for item in doc.items:
     emit [doc.category, item], null
    return

reduce: _count
```

more complex:

```
map.coffee: |
  (doc) ->
    emit doc.category, {items: 1, val: doc.value}
    return

reduce.coffee: |
  (keys, values, rereduce) ->
    ret = {items: 0, val: 0}
    for v in values
      ret.items += doc.items
      ret.val += doc.val
    return ret
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864420/change-filetype-or-other-vim-settings-blockwise-in-a-file shows a possible starting point for special cases

Comment: Can you please give more details, possible including some code as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you want it to make use of Vim's syntax regions (`:help syn-region`). But regions take delimiters as parameters.

You have a well defined start but not a defined end, maybe you could work your way around by establishing some conventions here like *"2 empty new lines at the end"*.

There are similar answers that might give you a hint (including the docs) on how to implement a solution, like: [Embedded syntax highligting in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519753/vimembedded-syntax-highligting)

Also interesting and similar approach is this Vimtip: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own syntax file, and define a syntax region for each of your entries. Inside that region, you can then syntax-include the corresponding language as defined by your `ext`. Read all the details at `:help :syn-include`.

If that sounds too complicated, check out my SyntaxRange plugin. It is based on the Vimtip mentioned by alfredodeza. With it, you can quickly assign a syntax to a range of lines, e.g. `:11,42SyntaxInclude perl`